# How to put application to background?

Tags: android, background-process

How to put application (activity?) to background so it can work there?

`moveTaskToBack(true);` doesn't work. I have `android:noHistory="true"` and this code:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    switch(keyCode)
    {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            moveTaskToBack(true);
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

What is wrong? How to put application to background?

**upd**: or maybe I can use moveTaskToBack(true) only in root (MAIN, LAUNCHER) activity?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to jump to the home screen because of some activity you can do this:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startActivity(i);
```

Just make sure you are running the code from your main activity thread. The "startActivity" implies this function is running from the main activity.

Answer (score 2):

`activity` are not made for background processes. Use [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) for your background processes.

Comment: Okay. But how to use Service? I want to make my program always available and to check new messages (just like Skype), but how it is possible? Maybe I should use Service just to check messages and to start Activity when notification is clicked?