# moveTaskToBack(true) returns false always

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I know this has been asked earlier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495188/how-to-put-application-to-background) & [here too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312334/how-to-handle-back-button-in-activity/5312426#5312426).They are not answered properly (or not answered at all).But,i don't know why `moveTaskToBack(true);` always returns false for me .Can anyone tell me why and how could i solve the issue? Thanks in advance.

```
public void onBackPressed() {       
    boolean r=  moveTaskToBack(true);
    //r is false !! using API LEVEL 8
}
```

Note:The activity from which i am calling it is a child `Activity` included in a `tabActivity` and neither of this is a **MAIN** or **LAUNCHER** activity.I don't know if that makes a difference.

**EDIT:**
and as a result the application does'nt go to background.I want it to go to background just as if the hardware HOME is pressed

Comment: Its working for me. I am also calling super.onBackPressed()

Comment: @Sweety are you calling it from the `MAIN'/'LAUNCHER' Activity?

Comment: @Sweety super.onBackPressed() exits the app and when you select it again from recent apps it relaunches it.I am testing this in API 8 emulator.

Comment: No it is from child activity. I think you will have to handle onResume()

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know why `moveTaskToBack(true)` is returning `false` for you. Perhaps there's something weird in your manifest? At any rate, you can do this instead to bring up the home screen:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
this.startActivity(i);
```

However, be aware of [this message](http://osdir.com/ml/Android-Developers/2010-03/msg01887.html):

> "You cannot simulate a press on the Home key." — Roman Guy, Android framework engineer

I'm not sure how that squares with my suggested code (which I found on the same thread as Roman's statement and seems to work).

Comment: This is a very good generic way. Put this in my baseActivity. Thanks!

Comment: Interestingly, when I am in the situation where `moveTaskToBack(true)` returns false, this code does nothing.

Comment: @androidguy - That is interesting. Do you know why `moveTaskToBack(true)` is returning false in the first place? Also, is there anything in the logs to indicate why my suggested code won't bring up the home screen? I would have thought that this would always work.

Comment: @TedHopp It is only on certain API levels such as M and maybe lower (not sure about L didn't check) when I return to task root activity with REORDER_TO_FRONT flag. It was "fixed" to work in this more unusual scenario in N seemingly. Just wanted to point this out in case someone tries to use it in the same scenario as me...

Answer (score 1):

Just write:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
    //  super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came into the similar problem(*a child Activity included in a tabActivity*), when you call moveTaskToBack(true) in the child activity, it doesn't work, whereas **it works in the parent activity**. You can call moveTaskToBack(true) in child activity like this:
`ChildActivity.this.getParent().moveTaskToBack(true)`